# Eclipse Helios/Galileo Update sites cannot be accessed on Windows machine with IE7

Tags: eclipse, user-agent, internet-explorer-7, galileo

When starting the update, the following error is displayed:

Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios".
    Error accessing site stream. [Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]
    Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
    Error accessing site stream. [Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]
    Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd

As described at

http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic
http://www.outofcontrol.ca/2009/02/20/w3org-dtdxhtml1-strictdtd-blocks-windows-ie-users/

w3.org blocks IE calls to http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd (as it is loading it much too frequently). I was able to load the DTD by setting a different UserAgent for IE7 using

%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent" /v Version /d "Opera/9.2.1" /f

I tried to -D overrides suggested at:

[Change user agent in Eclipse 3.5 for new software installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526956/change-user-agent-in-eclipse-3-5-for-new-software-installations)

to no avail. I think eclipse does not follow the User-Agent set by IE7 ...

Is there an other way to override the User-Agent for Eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to using the "classic updater" against Helios update site as described at

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=317957

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has gone "Market", joining AppStore by Apple and Marketplace by google.

From Help Menu, try **Eclipse Marketplace** instead of **Install New Software** to install and update your required plug-in

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem both on Galileo and Helios and Windows 7 64 bit, and have found yet no solution (adding a '/' or removing a '/' to the end of the update sites URLs does not work).

In Helios, at least, I have found that using the "Eclipse Marketplace" for updates/addins does work.