# Aptana studio 3 cannot contact download.ecplise.org

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I want to install a new plugin but i can't because aptana cannot reach the repository at download.ecplise.org (timeout)

Maybe it's a mirror that is down, there is a way to reset repository cache ?

There is an other way to get the missing plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

This usually is a transiant issue, and you should be able to install your plugin after simply restarting Aptana.

See for instance [this thread](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2703), with a similar plugin installation issue:

[image: Aptana plugin installation issue]

That kind of [error message was also found here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/938-pdt-installation-issues-timeout-way-to-downloadinstall-manually):

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed 
session context was: 
(profile=AptanaProfile, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, 
operand=, action=). 
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/rt/swordfish/updates/plugins/org.mortbay.management_6.1.15.v200910261235.jar. Read timed out
```

And the "solution" was:

> Nevermind. I have no idea why, but after restarting again and retrying, again, it worked. I have no idea why though!

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121862/eclipse-helios-galileo-update-sites-cannot-be-accessed-on-windows-machine-with-ie). Eclipse is updating to a "marketplace" mechanism for update and aptana is still on the "classic update". I don't know how to manage to get my plug ins or the marketplace mechanism to work.

Comment: @Solune: And I suppose Aptana is based on Helios, not Indigo?

Comment: right... v_v but it seems that Helios have a working version with the marketplace, aptana's dev may have a update in the pipe, for that

Comment: @Solune: I thought the Studio 3 (like 3.0.2 https://aptana.com/products/studio3/releasenotes) was compatible with Indigo (maybe not yet with its update mechanism though).