# Eclipse Marketplace not showing up (missing) on 3.7 Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I installed the Eclipse Marketplace via http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/ and Help>Install New Software... and it's not showing up under the help menu as expected after a complete reboot and I can't seem to find anyone else who is having this problem?

What led me to installing the Eclipse Marketplace in the first place was my attempt to install Eclipse Color Themes (http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update/). Eclipse Color Themes did not appear where indicated in it's documentation either so I thought I would attempt installing through the marketplace but I think I may have a larger plug-in related issue however plug-ins like Aptana and other misc. custom plug-ins installed correctly.

I'm running Eclipse on Windows 7 64-bit if that's of any help as well.

Comment: Your post suggests that you are using Eclipse Indigo.  If so, Eclipse Marketplace _should be_ part of the IDE out-of-the-box.  As for the color themes that you are trying to install what do you mean "it isn't showing up under the help menu"?  Per instructions (https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme) you should look under Window > Preferences > Appearance > Color Theme.  And it is indeed there.

Comment: When I said, "It's not showing up under the help menu" I was talking about the Eclipse Marketplace. Color themes did not show up under Window > Preferences > Appearance > Color Theme either.

The Eclipse Marketplace was in fact not installed when I checked it before installing it but it's installed now, just not showing up which is odd to me since my entire Aptana plug-in is functional.

Comment: Not the first time I see issue between Aptana and marketplace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607768/aptana-studio-3-cannot-contact-download-ecplise-org

Comment: According to http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/, MPC is included in all of the EPP download package (with the exception of Classic).

Comment: Wow this question has gotten a lot of feedback, personally I upgraded to Juno and haven't had any problems.

Comment: I have the same issue now.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem.
I add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo repo and install MPC and Maven.

Answer (score 4):

I tried @d_pilot's answer which didn't work but found the repo at <strike>http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/</strike>

You should be able to change the /mpc/(version)/ to get whatever you want from there, which is nice for all the other eclipse classic versions.

more current link: http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/archive.php

Comment: Doesn't work for Juno. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11403176/660311 for how to get the marketplace in more recent versions.

Comment: Newer link added better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

To add some Google search terms:

I had this issue when installing via Ubuntu apt-get package management and ransom bot's answer worked for me.