# Install Marketplace plugin on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-marketplace

I downloaded the [Eclipse Juno 4.2 classic bundle](http://eclipse.org/downloads/), and saw that `Help > Marketplace...` was not available. AFAIK, this is provided by the [mpc plugin. On their website](http://eclipse.org/mpc/) however, I didn't see a trace of how to install the mpc client for Juno.

How can I add the Marketplace Client to the classic Juno bundle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623/how-do-i-install-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-classic)

Comment: Please refer this -> [How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623/how-do-i-install-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-classic

Have fun! @.@

Thanks

Answer (score 232, accepted):

As far as I know, the Classic distribution does not contain the Marketplace client (and that is the only such official distribution). However, it is available for download.

Select Help/Install new software... from the menu, select the Juno update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno), and then look for the Marketplace client - it is in the General Purpose Tools category.

Comment: Can confirm this works exactly the same in Eclipse Mars (4.5), just change `juno` to `mars`

Answer (score 11):

There is one More easy way to add Eclipse MarketPlace
1. Go to http://eclipse.org/mpc/archive.php and download mpc zip for your eclipse.
2. Than go to Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software and Add and select Archive file Location 
  then press ok, it will check dependency and install it.
And Enjoy....