# Cannot Install Aptana plugin on Eclipse 4.2

Tags: ruby, eclipse, aptana, eclipse-juno

I've installed Eclipse 4.2 Juno. Now I want to install aptana for developing ruby, but I get the following error,

> Unable to read repository at http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/content.jar.

Unable to read repository at http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install/content.jar.
Read timed out

Comment: You should accept the answer below aka most popular - it works ;)

Answer (score 80):

I assume that by now you have probably solved the problem, but I had exactly the same problem and found the solution after many searches, so for the sake of any others searching here...

The URL you need to enter in the 'Install New Software' dialog is

```
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
```

Comment: Really helpful. I wonder why it isn't updated on their website.

Answer (score 17):

The following answer was correct. I just tested it with Eclipse Juno.

Steps:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Help -> Install New Software
3. Add (on the top right)
4. Enter the following link for Aptana Plugin with Eclipse Juno: http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
5. Click OK
6. Put a check mark for Aptana Studio 3
7. Next -> Next -> Finish

Answer (score 7):

download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install did not work for me. I am using Eclipse 4.3 based STS 3.4

Instead I got the appropriate update site link from this site [Aptana Update Site](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio3/3.4.2.201308081736/index.html)

This is the link for Eclipse plugin update site http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio3/3.4.2.201308081736/

There is also a link to download the plugin and install through archive. I have used the above update site link and no problem at all.

Hope that will help others.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this answer in case somebody still gets this error while using the correct URL from JonB's answer (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install )

Restart Eclipse and try again.
This appears to be a transient issue, as mentioned here:
[Aptana studio 3 cannot contact download.ecplise.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607768/aptana-studio-3-cannot-contact-download-ecplise-org)

It worked for me after a retry.

Answer (score 1):

I also gone through same problem. But Following solution works for me,

In Eclipse, go to  "Eclipse Marketplace" and search for Aptana 3 and hit the Install button.

Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace

[Eclipse Market place - Aptana 3 Studio plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/logYa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wondered myself whether to install the standalone or the plugin. I tried the plugin based on aptanaès instructions and it failed on the first try.

As usual SO respondents reported this problem.

I restarted Eclipse, and then did the install with Aptanaès URL

http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

and it worked.

My environment was Eclipse JUNO,

Answer (score 0):

As of 01/29/18 and Eclipse Photon, none of the URLs listed as answers here work in Eclipse's built-in software sources panel. However, after some trial and error mashing up Aptana's old download URLs with the ones Appcelerator (which bought Aptana in 2015) uses for its own software, I got:

http://download.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/stable

This works, is totally plug-and-play, and is obviously official - no need to go off to some shady 3rd party hosting site. I just wish someone at Appcelerator had spent 15 minutes to post it somewhere.